# Editing of compiled resource file DLL's

Tags: .net

I am globalizing my application to accommodate English and Norwegian language. So I have created two files named xx.resx file and xx.nb-NO.resx. After the compilation, I need to give this resource file DLL to someone who knows Norwaegian to edit. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't need the dll, just send them the .resx file which is basically just XML they can edit.  You'll then need to update and recompile your app/project when they send it back and update your dll or redeploy.